# Separating A String Into Characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I have some ordered test results encoded in a character string. The string can be of arbitrary length. Each digit in the string represents a test result. In the following, for example, there are four test results represented:

`2069`

I want to tidy these up in R by splitting the string into individual observations. No problem with `strsplit` or `string::str_split`, which returns four values that will become my observations.

```
strsplit("2069" %>% as.character(), split = "") %>% unlist()
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"
```

Now, however, I have realized that some results are values greater than 9. These two-digit values have been encoded with parentheses to make clear they are not individual results.

For example, in the following case I still have four values, but some have been enclosed in parentheses to group the values larger than 9.

`2(10)1(12)`

I'm struggling with a way to break these up so that I get

`[1] "2" "10" "1" "12"`

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated - pattern match based on the OP's new pattern showed in the comments.  Here, we use `str_extract` to extract one or more digits that follow an open parentheses (`regex lookaround` ) or (`|`) any character that is not a parentheses (`[^()]`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, "(?<=[(])\\d+|[^()]")
[[1]]
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"

[[3]]
[1] "2"  "15"

[[4]]
[1] "2" "1" "3" "1"
```

-testing on the OP's extra pattern

```
str_extract_all(str2, "(?<=[(])\\d+|[^()]")
[[1]]
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"

[[3]]
[1] "2"  "15"

[[4]]
[1] "2" "1" "3" "1"

[[5]]
[1] "10" "0"  "2"  "0"  "1"
```

---

-Earlier solutions (Based on the assumption that all the numbers that are greater than 9 will be wrapped inside the parentheses)

We may split on the parentheses in `base R`

```
unlist(strsplit(str1[1], "\\(|\\)"))
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"
```

---

Assuming if there are both cases, then an option is to get the index of those elements have the parentheses and do this separately

```
i1 <- grepl("\\(|\\)", str1)
lst1 <- vector('list', length(str1))
lst1[i1] <- strsplit(str1[i1], "\\(|\\)")
lst1[!i1] <- strsplit(str1[!i1], "")
unlist(lst1)
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12" "2"  "0"  "6"  "9"  "2"  "15" "2"  "1"  "3"  "1"
```

---

or another option is `ifelse` with `grepl` to create a single delimiter and then use `strsplit`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(trimws(ifelse(grepl("\\(|\\)", str1), 
    gsub("\\(|\\)", ",", str1), gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", "\\1,\\2", 
       str1, perl = TRUE)), whitespace = ","), ",")
lst1
[[1]]
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"

[[3]]
[1] "2"  "15"

[[4]]
[1] "2" "1" "3" "1"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("2(10)1(12)", "2069", "2(15)", "2131")
str2 <- c(str1, "(10)0201")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @akrun. I didn't articulate my problem clearly enough and have edited it for clarity. The issue is that each encoded value represents one test result unless the value is greater than 9, in which case the test result is enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @RDelRossi I updated the post to check for those cases having `()`. can you please check the second part of my solution

Comment: The last option is super compact and impressive, amazing!

Comment: This is very close. Thank you. I need trace through your logic as I have a test case that's not working, "(10)0201", but I appreciate very much you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @RDelRossi the last option still works with that

Comment: Actually, @akrun, that last ultra-compact version, handled my outlier problem case now, too.

Comment: @akrun: Brilliant. Thank you, Arun, for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @RDelRossi I would say that case was anomaly as per your logic i.e. the main logic was if a number is greater than 9, it would be inside parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can do like below (borrow `str1` from [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876566/12158757))

```
> mapply(strsplit, str1, ifelse(grepl("[()]", str1), "\\(|\\)", ""))
$`2(10)1(12)`
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"

$`2069`
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"

$`2(15)`
[1] "2"  "15"

$`2131`
[1] "2" "1" "3" "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```r
(?<=\()\d+(?=\))|\d
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6EHQBG/1/%5D).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
```

**[R code](https://tio.run/##JYxLCoAwDET3nqJklaCCqSgIihcpSP0gQnERu1Dw7rXqah7zmJEQ3DaKlQsPL9u@CiURWLW5mhA0ckGMrAkyBbqomy@Rq7/gkuEbDMvpxU5@sM69Txwt9m1nDJIxc4p9RKI7MlAIDw)**:

```r
library(stringr)
str1 <- c("2(10)1(12)", "2069", "2(15)", "2131")
str_extract_all(str1, "(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))|\\d")
```

**Results**:

```
[1] "2"  "10" "1"  "12"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "0" "6" "9"

[[3]]
[1] "2"  "15"

[[4]]
[1] "2" "1" "3" "1"
```